# OnPause to stop GPS

Tags: android

UPDATE #2.  My initial question was solved by the kindness of the two who answered.  Apparently I need to start a new question for the fact that the resulting code, while it runs, does not stop the GPS.  But there are no errors now so I would mark this as solved if I knew how :-)

UPDATE.

I have "working" code thanks to comments the only problem is that it doesn't do what it is supposed to do.  It is working in that there are no errors.

To make it work, I added this globally at the top of the activity.

```
    protected LocationListener ll;
protected LocationManager lm;
```

And used this OnPause code

```
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        if(lm != null) {
            lm.removeUpdates(ll);
        }
        ll = null;
        lm = null;
        super.onPause();
    }
```

Everything compiles and runs on a phone. I get GPS locations displayed.  Trouble is that the goal is to get the GPS to turn off so that the battery doesn't go dead after leaving the application.  But the GPS stays on.  I see this is a common complaint and have not seen an answer.  I thought lm.removeUpdates(ll) was the solution but it isn't working.

--------------- original post -------------------------

I want to add some OnPause code to stop my GPS updates.  I have tired at least a dozen examples of code from stackoverflow both questions and answers and all give errors in Eclipse.

My GPS code is here (it works fine):

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textLat = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textLat);
    textLong = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textLong);
    textTimex = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textTimex);
    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocationListener ll = new mylocationlistener();
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, ll);
}
    class mylocationlistener implements LocationListener{

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            if (location != null)
            {
                double pLat = location.getLatitude();
                double pLong = location.getLongitude();
                long pTime = location.getTime();
                DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.######");
                textLat.setText(df.format(pLat));
                textLong.setText(df.format(pLong));
                textTimex.setText(Long.toString(pTime));
                //textTimex.setText(Long.toString(pTime));
                //textTimex.setText(df.format(pLong));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        } 
    }
```

I am taking code from examples on the web and none of them work.  Here is one

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    lm.removeUpdates(locationListener);
    super.onPause();
}
```

It really doesn't matter what I call lm, it gives an error that it cannot resolve it.  It doesn't matter which example code I use, none of them are error free.

I must be doing something very simply stupid...

Answer (score 1):

declare `locationListener` globally(outside from onCreate method of Activity) as:

```
    LocationListener ll;
     @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ////your code...
       ll = new mylocationlistener();
       ////your code..
    }


   @Override protected void onPause() 
 { 
  super.onPause();
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
   System.out.println("a intrat in onPause()"); 
  if(lm != null) { 
    lm.removeUpdates(ll); 
  } 
  ll = null; 
  lm = null;  
}
```

Comment: If I declare both ll and lm globally the application compiles and runs but crashes when I exit that activity.  What I have is         @Override
        public void onPause() {
            lm.removeUpdates(ll);
        }

Comment: @AllenEdwards : can you provide log when app is crashing

Comment: @AllenEdwards : try as `public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    lm.removeUpdates(ll);
}`

Comment: It doesn't crash with the changes listed below but it also doesn't seem to be turning off the GPS.  Unfortuniately, it does crash with the code suggested just above.

Comment: @AllenEdwards : and with this code `@Override protected void onPause() { super.onPause();// TODO Auto-generated method stub System.out.println("a intrat in onPause()"); if(lm != null) { lm.removeUpdates(ll); } ll = null; lm = null;  }`

Comment: that new code is what I am using except the super.onPause is in a different place.  I tried it both places, same result: It still doesn't turn off the GPS when you exit the activity.

Comment: @AllenEdwards : this is not fine you have changed question when one problem is solved ok. for which i have give you solution. if you have any other issue like gps not Stopping then ask new question without editing original question.Thanks so much. if this answer really help you then mark it as answer and ask another question for other issue without Editing this Question.Thanks

Comment: Sorry, didn't know the protocol and didn't want to overload the board with basically the same question (stopping GPS).  This is solved in that the code now runs, it just doesn't do anything.  I will ask a new question and mark this as solved.  Thank you and rekire for your hlep

Answer (score 0):

The variables you are trying to use are just visible in the scope of onCreate. You need to use a member variable.

You need into your class a:

```
protected LocationListener ll;
protected LocationManager lm;
```

Then you just need to remove the LocationListener before your ll and use ll into your onPause code. And the same for lm and the type LocationManager.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textLat = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textLat);
    textLong = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textLong);
    textTimex = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textTimex);
    lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    ll = new mylocationlistener();
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, ll);
}
```

Comment: Not sure exactly what you are saying but I added protected LocationListener ll; and same for lm and changed my OnPause code to another example and it doesn't crash.It also doesn't shut down the GPS.          @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("a intrat in onPause()");
            if(lm != null) {
                lm.removeUpdates(ll);
            }
            ll = null;
            lm = null;
            super.onPause();
        }